# How do I load the previous page after submitting a form in php?

Tags: php, function, redirect, header

I'm having trouble on how to redirect the page to the previous one after submitting a form in php. My site has this header that is used for all of my pages and it contains this "add" button which sends the form to my "add.php". I'm not sure if using the header() function of php would solve it.

Comment: Yeah, but I got an error.

Answer (score 4):

You shall try in `php`

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Or via `javascript`

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

If you just want to navigate to the page after some action is done, you shall use `action` in your form.

Here is the fully constructed function that you look for

```
function goback()
{
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    exit;
}

goback();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the action='nameofyourpreviouspage.fileextention' inside your form tag.

Like this:

```
<form action="nameofyourpreviouspage.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
header("location:pagename.php");
```

or

You shall try in php

```
function return()
{
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<?php
```

?>`   or might u have problem with headers ob_start();
and ob_flush();
in begging and ending of the programme respectievely .it should work.thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just add  $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] to the action which is a super global variable that returns the filename of the currently executing script and sends the submitted form data to the page itself, instead of jumping to a different page

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).